# Build in Z3 python a list of tuples

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

I am attempting to use Z3 solver in python to create a predicate `path(list)` which returns true if the `list` is a valid path on a given graph `G`

I would like to construct a list of tuples using Z3 to represent all edges present in the graph, here is my first attempt:

```py
from z3 import *

IntPair = TupleSort("IntPair", [IntSort(), IntSort()])

List = Datatype('List')
List.declare('list', ('head', IntPair), ('tail', List))
List.declare('empty')
List = List.create()
```

However I am getting an error:

> Z3Exception: Valid list of accessors expected. An accessor is a pair of the form (String, Datatype|Sort)

From this line:

```
List.declare('list', ('head', IntPair), ('tail', List))
```

I am not sure which accessor is violating and causing this error. If we consider a list of integers:

```
List.declare('list', ('head', IntSort()), ('tail', List))
```

The above will run without errors.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the definition of `IntPair`?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger apologies, `IntPairSort` should be `IntPair`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `TupleSort` it returns a triple. The sort, a constructor, and the accessors. You need to pattern-match and give each a separate name. That is, replace your line:

```py
IntPair = TupleSort("IntPair", [IntSort(), IntSort()])
```

with:

```py
IntPair, mkIntPair, (first, second) = TupleSort("IntPair", [IntSort(), IntSort()])
```

Now `IntPair` is the name of the sort you wanted; and the rest of your program will go without any errors.

As you develop your program further, you'll need to use `mkIntPair`, `first` and `second` as you access and construct those pairs inside your list.